# What's the inline here for?

Tags: c, syntax

What's the difference between the 2 definitions below:

```
#define DEFINE_BIT_MASK_ENUM_AND_OR(Type) \
inline Type EnumBitMaskOr(Type lhs, Type rhs) { return lhs | rhs; } \

#define DEFINE_BIT_MASK_ENUM_AND_OR(Type) \
Type EnumBitMaskOr(Type lhs, Type rhs) { return lhs | rhs; } \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "`inline`" signals to some compilers that the function should be inlined if possible, i.e. the code from the function's body should be "copy pasted" into the call site, rather than generated as a stand-alone function.

This can save time, since if the work being done is smaller than the work in doing the call itself, it's a net win to remove it. It can also slow things down, by bloating the code and killing the cache.

Comment: ` the function should be inlined if possible`,you mentioned `if possible`,is there a case in which inline is impossible?

Comment: @wp2 yes, for example if it is recursive, or too long

Comment: Can you provide an example for recursive and too long respectively?

Comment: @wp2: inline int f(int x) {return x <= 0 ? 1 : f(x-1); } this will most likely NOT be inlined

Comment: @wp2: read my answer. The compiler decides whether or not to inline the call practically regardless of you declaring the function as inline

Comment: In the case that can't be inlined,will it raise a error/warning ?

Comment: @wp2: NO! It won't. The MAIN thing about inline is point 1 of my answer. The actual inlining is something the compiler may or may not do. And it can actually inline a function even if it is NOT declared as inline

Answer (score 2):

Since to my taste all the answers, even the accepted one, get the main aspect of `inline` wrong and in particular in what it means for the use in macros, I try another one.

The `inline` keyword determines if a function definition (not declaration) will result in the generation of the function in the current compilation unit. There are basically 3 cases:

- If you just put a "plain" definition
  the function *must* be generated and
  an external symbol for that function
  is inserted.
- For an `inline` definition a function
  *may* be generated and if so this may or may not insert an external symbol
  to the object.
- For a `static` definition a function
  *may* be generated (usually if it is used) but the name will never be an
  external symbol.

For the first, if two compilation units define the same function there will be an error when linking the two object files together in one executable.

For the later, if two compilation units define the same function both object files will contain copies of the function that will not be merged when they are linked.

With respect to the macros that are presented in the question this makes an important functional difference. The first, `inline`, can be expanded anywhere especially in a header file without causing conflicts. The second can only be use in a .c file and in addition no two such .c should do that if they should end up in the same executable.

---

**Edit:** w.r.t to  Charles' comment. `inline` functions may well be also external symbols. The rules for that are a bit complex, see the corresponding paragraph 6.7.4 from C99 below. Basically there are three cases that will work if you have several translation units that will be linked together

1. declare and define the function
   `extern inline` in a .h file and *declare* it again just
   `inline` without `extern` in exactly one .c file.
2. declare and define the function
   `inline` in a .h file and redeclare it without
   `inline` in exactly one .c file. This is in fact    similar to the instantiation of template functions in C++.
3. declare and define the function
       `inline` in a .h file and redeclare it 
       `extern inline` in exactly one .c file.

Before version 4.3, gcc had a different model for this type of instantiation of `inline` functions that is incompatible with this normative one. [See also this page for a good read on this subject.](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2003/03/inline.html)

> Any function with internal linkage can
>   be an inline function. For a function
>   with external linkage, the following
>   restrictions apply: If a function is
>   declared with an inline function
>   specifier, then it shall also be
>   defined in the same translation unit.
>   If all of the file scope declarations
>   for a function in a translation unit
>   include the inline function specifier
>   without extern, then the definition in
>   that translation unit is an inline
>   definition. An inline definition does
>   not provide an external definition for
>   the function, and does not forbid an
>   external definition in another
>   translation unit. An inline definition
>   provides an alternative to an external
>   definition, which a translator may use
>   to implement any call to the function
>   in the same translation unit. It is
>   unspecified whether a call to the
>   function uses the inline definition or
>   the external definition.

Comment: If I've understood what you are saying then I don't believe that it is correct. In C `inline` definitions never provide an external definition for a function (even if a function definition is created). In C, a function can have one non-inline external definition and multiple inline definitions. The inline definitions need not be the same as each other or as the external definition but it is only the external definition that is visible to other translation units.

Comment: @Charles: I think what you describe is the gcc version of it which was in effect before release 4.3. C99 has a different model, see my edit. That model effectively allows to pick out one translation unit where an `inline` function will be instantiated and will be made an external symbol. (Makes debugging much easier :)

Comment: I was trying to describe the ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 version of inline. It looks like I failed. I'm not sure what you mean in paragraph 1. What would adding another `inline` declaration in a .c file do according to the standard? I can't see how it would have any additional effect on the translation unit.

Comment: @Charles: This is certainly not an easy read. For 1, perhaps I was not clear enough I mean a declaration that contains `inline` without `extern`. Such a translation unit sees multiple declarations of the function, where one is not `extern`. So the definition is not an inline definition. All other translation units only see the `extern inline` definition, so for them this is an inline definition.

Comment: By my reading, you have it backwards; if all the declarations for the function have inline *without* extern, then the required definition of the function is an inline definition and doesn't provide and external definition for the function. Conversely, if at least one declaration for the function either includes `extern` or lacks `inline`, then the definition provides an external definition for the function.

Comment: @Charles: for the unit that also declares without extern, it sees two different things, one `inline` and one `extern inline`. Now since one declaration is with `extern` it has external linkage, so `the restrictions apply`. Under these restrictions it only would be an inline definition, if the unit would see only `inline`. So it isn't an inline definition. Probably I am explaining it badly. I'll add a link to a page that explains this better.

Comment: The restrictions apply, but the restrictions say "if _all_ of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline function specifier without extern..." but this isn't the case as it is declared once _with_ `extern` so it's not (just) an inline definition.

Comment: @Charles: I don't see a thing like "just an inline definition" in that text. A definition is either an inline definition or it isn't. Here in that case it is not, as you say. So it is the definition of an external symbol and code is emitted in the object, the symbol for that code is external and can be called from other translation units.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: I was using "just" to highlight the fact that a definition for an inline function that also provides an external definition can be used in the translation unit that it is defined for inline expansion. You can delete it without affecting my point.

Comment: @Charles: any function definition that is visible to the compiler can be used for an inline expansion. You don't need to mark it `inline` for that. So what remains as a property to know whether or not a function will be emitted as an external symbol is if it is an inline definition or not. Here it isn't. So it will be emitted as an external symbol. Then, at places where the function is called inside the same unit the compiler can do as pleases because he has seen a definition. In any case, we should stop here, this doesn't lead much further, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in first case no function invokation is happening. The function is 'inlined', which means the calling is replaced with method body. It helps to optimize the execution as no context have to be saved before the invokation and restored afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It is a keyword that was valid mainly when compilers were not good enough to determine for themselves whether or not it is preferrable to inline. Todays modern compilers are often a lot better at determining this, using link-time code generation if necessary (whole-program analysis).

Answer (score 0):

The "inline" keyword is used to indicate to the compiler that you would like it to perform inline expansion of the function, or in other words expand the function in place of the call.

A few points to make

1. The reason this is usually done is to save the overhead of calling another function
2. the "inline" keyword is only a request to the compiler and the compiler can decide whether to honour it or not
3. Inlining can have unintended consequences so should be used with caution
4. Compiler todays usually do a better job of deciding which functions should be inlined for you and will do that automatically if the appropriate arguments are provided to your compiler

Answer (score 0):

I noted in comments to [unwind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265987/whats-the-inline-here-for/4266017#4266017) that you wanted to know the following:

If a function can't be inlined, and was marked so you will get a warning if you pass [`-Winline`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) to GCC.